# Jssocials not working in UIWebView/WKWebView

Tags: objective-c, facebook, uiwebview, instagram, wkwebview

I want to use jssocial plugin in iOS,there is no response when user clicks on buttons be it a Facebook, twitter or Instagram from UIWebView and also not from WKWebView so, if anybody have implemented it in iOS then please guide me about it.
Any help will be appreciable. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Set WKWebView properties and delegates as follow

```
 WKPreferences *prefs = [WKPreferences new];
prefs.javaScriptEnabled = YES;
prefs.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = YES;
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
theConfig.preferences = prefs;
webView = [[EasyJSWKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds
                                       configuration:theConfig
                            withJavascriptInterfaces:interfaces];
    webView.UIDelegate = self;
    webView.navigationDelegate = self;

   [webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior =  UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
    }
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];


    - (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:  (WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures
  {
ViewPopUp = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[ViewPopUp setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview:ViewPopUp];
UIButton *btnBack = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 50, 50)];
[btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[ViewPopUp addSubview:btnBack];
PopUpView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-64) configuration:configuration];
 PopUpView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = YES;
PopUpView.navigationDelegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:PopUpView];
return PopUpView;
 }
```